# My actuators in spring boot are not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to check whether my spring boot application is up and running via spring boot actuators. My spring boot application annotation contains this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class EntityManagerFactory
})
```

In my application properties file I have `management.server.port=8081`. But when I start up my application and try to run `localhost:8081/actuator/info` I got an error - **This site can not be reached**.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which version of Spring boot are you using?

Comment: My spring boot version is 2.0.1.RELEASE.

Comment: In your `pom.xml` you have to import the dependency `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. Did you have it?

Comment: Yes, I am using gradle - compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator").

Comment: If you have server.servlet.context-path configured in your application.properties, then your actuator will be available on http://localhost:8081/{context-path}/actuator. Also, it should be "actuator" not "actuators"

Comment: Actuators in spring boot 2 require security settings, check out this link for an example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators or provide details of your security settings

Comment: Yes sorry I was trying /actuator (just misstyped in text). I have not set servlet context path in my application.properties.

Comment: I am not running spring security in my app.

Comment: I would suggest looking in your application's logfile to see if the actuator endpoint was exposed. There needs to be lines similar to these: 
Mapped "{[/actuator/health]
Mapped "{[/actuator/info]
Mapped "{[/actuator]

Comment: If you have not set any context-path, you should try to call `localhost:8081/info`.

Comment: @mdewit My log is not showing that it has Mapped anything. Also I do not have any context-path set.

Comment: Maybe post your log file as well as application.properties. Also your maven/gradle dependencies section